# react router - don't match multiple paths (v4)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have the following react-router configuration

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
  <Route exact path='/sign-in' component={SignIn} />
  <Route exact path='/:username' component={Profile} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

When on a profile page like `/dylan` the Profile component matches and :username param is "dylan" like I would expect.

When navigating to the `/sign-in` route, the  component gets rendered and the  component get rendered too (with `sign-in` as the username)

What is the idiomatic solution with react-router v4 to prevent routes from matching multiple components?

versions:

- react-router-dom 4.1.2

Comment: use the `<Switch>` component

Comment: That's not a good piece of design. It's better to consider having /sign-in and /users/:username instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Battle_Slug is right. It's actually better to differentiate the route `/sign-in` and `/user/:username`

But If you really need it, you can do it this way

```
function CheckInitialParam(props) {
  if (props.match.params.intialParam === 'sign-in') {
     return <SignIn />
  } else {
     return <Profile />
  }
}
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/:intialParam" component={CheckInitialParam} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Using `<Switch>`also right.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/sign-in' component={SignIn} />
    <Route path='/:username' component={Profile} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Reference : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch